For $f : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $f$ is bounded and continuous at $p \in [a, b]$, $\lim_{x \rightarrow p^-}$ inf$(f([x, p])) = f(p)$
I know that because $f$ is bounded and $f([x, p])$ is non-empty for $x \in [a, p)$, then inf$(f([x, p]))$ exists and is in the closure of $f([x, p])$. However, wouldn't I need inf$(f([x, p])) \in f([x, p])$ to use the epsilon delta definition of a limit?
Because, if inf$(f([x, p])) \in f([x, p])$, I know that:
$\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $x \in [a, b]$ and $0 < p - x < \delta$ implies $\lvert f(x) - f(p) \rvert < \epsilon$, from which I can then say: $\lvert $ inf$f([x, p]) - f(p) \rvert < \epsilon$, because there must exist some $x'$ delta-close to $p$ such that $f(x') = $inf$(f([x, p]))$.
I don't know if my initial claim is wrong or the logic above, but any help would be appreciated.

You need $p>a$ for the question to make sense. Not just $p\in[a,b]$.

Your boundedness hypothesis is useless. By continuity at $p$, $f$ is bounded near $p$.

Your argument "there must exist some $x'$ delta-close to $p$ such that $f(x') = $inf$(f([x, p]))$" is wrong because $f$ is only assumed to be continuous at $p$. A correct proof is simply: $$\forall\epsilon>0;\exists\delta>0;f([p-\delta,p])\subseteq [f(p)-\epsilon,f(p)+\epsilon]$$ hence for every $x\in[p-\delta,p]$, $f([x, p])\subseteq[ f(p)-\epsilon,f(p)+\epsilon]$ and a fortiori $\inf(f([x, p]))\in [f(p)-\epsilon,f(p)+\epsilon]$.

Let $\epsilon >0$. There exists $\delta >0$ such that $|f(y)-f(p)| <\epsilon$ if $p-\delta <y<p$. Let $p-\delta <x<p$. Then, for any $y \in [x,p]$ we have $p-\delta <y<p$. Hence, $|f(y)-f(p)| <\epsilon$ and this implies $f(y) >f(p)-\epsilon $. Taking infimum over all $y \in [x,p]$ we get $\inf (f(x,p]) \ge f(p)-\epsilon $ whenever $p-\delta <x<p$. The rest is clear.
